# How to simplify a 4-variable Boolean Expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am doing some simplifications on 4-Variable Boolean Expressions and I am kind of stuck. According to my K-Map simplification, I am actually supposed to get $(B'+C'+D')(A'+C'+D)$ only and I have no idea how to proceed further. Could anyone help me on this? Let me know as well if I did something wrong below.

Original Equation:
$(A+B'+C'+D')(A'+B'+C')(A'+C'+D)$

Required Output:
$(B'+C'+D')(A'+C'+D)$

My working so far:
Let $Y = (B'+C')$
$=(A+Y+D')(A'+Y)(A'+C'+D)$
$=(Y+A+D')(Y+A')(A'+C'+D)$
$=(Y+(A+D')(A'))(A'+C'+D)$
$=(Y+(AA'+A'D'))(A'+C'+D)$
$=(Y+A'D')(A'+C'+D)$
Substitute back $Y$
$=((B'+C')+A'D')(A'+C'+D)$
$=(A'+B'+C')(B'+C'+D')(A'+C'+D)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [Consensus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem), which states that
$$(\color{lightblue}{A}+B)(\color{orange}{C}+B')(\color{lightblue}{A}+\color{orange}{C})=(\color{lightblue}{A}+B)(\color{orange}{C}+B')$$
Follows from your work, which is correct, directly apply Consensus theorem we have
\begin{align}
&(A+B′+C′+D′)(A′+B′+C′)(A′+C′+D)\\
=&(B′+C′+D′)(A′+C′+D)(B′+C′+A′)\tag*{Your work}\\
=&(\color{lightblue}{B′+C′}+D′)(\color{orange}{A′+C′}+D)(\color{lightblue}{B′+C′}+\color{orange}{A′+C′})\\
=&(\color{lightblue}{B′+C′}+D′)(\color{orange}{A′+C′}+D)
\end{align}